# ruby: FileUtils produces mad content

Tags: ruby, shell

Corresponding to this that code

```
[checker.rb]
require 'dir'
require 'fileutils'
module Checker

  # Checks if the targetdirectory are present. If not, it creates one
  def self.check_dir
    # Checking if dir exists
    if Dir.exist?("#{@todo}")
      puts 'Found directory. Im using it.'
    else
      puts 'No directory found. Im creating it.'
      # Creates the new directory
      FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{@todo}")
        if Dir.exist?("#{@todo}")
          puts 'Created new directory...'
        else
          raise('Cant create directory')
        end
    end
  end
end



 [main]
    home = Dir.home
    publican_doc_dir = "#{home}/Dokumente/Textdokumente/publican-dokumentation2"
    articles_dir = "#{publican_doc_dir}/articles"
titel = `yad --entry --button="Bestätigen" --title="Neuen Artikel erstellen" --text="Gebe ein Titel ein (Mit Unterstrichen statt Leerzeichen und ohne Umlaute):"`
    [...]
    puts "Erstellt Verzeichnis #{articles_dir}/#{titel}"
    @todo = "#{articles_dir}/#{titel}"
    Checker.check_dir

    puts 'Wechsle in article Verzeichnis'
    FileUtils.cd("#{articles_dir}/#{titel}") do

    [...stuff...]

    end
```

and the full code [there](https://github.com/saigkill/PublicanCreators/tree/master/lib) i'm getting the false result. It should be articles/test01 instead of articles/test01?/test01.

```
sascha@sascha-desktop:~/Dokumente/Textdokumente/publican-dokumentation2/articles$ ls
Test01?  Test02?  Test03?

sascha@sascha-desktop:~/Dokumente/Textdokumente/publican-dokumentation2/articles$ cd Test03?
sascha@sascha-desktop:~/Dokumente/Textdokumente/publican-dokumentation2/articles/Test03$ ls
Test03

sascha@sascha-desktop:~/Dokumente/Textdokumente/publican-dokumentation2/articles/Test03/Test03$ ls
de-DE  publican.cfg
```

The content there should be placed one level further. Maybe anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see minimal code demonstrating the problem *in the question* not as a link. Links rot and die, but with the minimal code example embedded in the question it will remain viable. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I thought it is better to not made duplicated content. But i've added the missed thing now :-)

Comment: I haven't used `yad` but the extra character after "test01" makes me think that you need to `chomp` the `titel` variable. As a quick test just after the  `titel =` line, put in a new additional line `titel=titel.chomp` and see if that behaves differently.

Comment: That solves the first problem. The extra char now is gone :-) Thank you. Now i just have the problem with double folders. Like articles/Test03/Test03.

Comment: Now i just have the problem with double folders. Like articles/Test03/Test03. Maybe anyone has a hint?